# Adding subtotal / grand total row in pandas muiltiindex produces tuple as an index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'category': {1050: 'Dining',
  992: 'Dining',
  1054: 'Kitchen',
  1052: 'Kitchen',
  993: 'Living room',
  980: 'Living room',
  996: 'Dining',
  1017: 'Dining',
  1020: 'Bath',
  1001: 'Bath'},
 'subcategory': {1050: 'Chairs',
  992: 'Chairs',
  1054: 'Stool',
  1052: 'Mirror',
  993: 'mirror',
  980: 'chair',
  996: 'Chairs',
  1017: 'Chairs',
  1020: 'Table',
  1001: 'Table'},
 'discount': {1050: '30-40',
  992: '30-40',
  1054: '30-40',
  1052: '30-40',
  993: '30-40',
  980: '30-40',
  996: '30-40',
  1017: '30-40',
  1020: '30-40',
  1001: '30-40'},
 'sales_1': {1050: 9539.86,
  992: 12971.86,
  1054: 6736.53,
  1052: 7163.16,
  993: 8601.16,
  980: 8047.16,
  996: 16322.0,
  1017: 14424.32,
  1020: 6319.58,
  1001: 4551.42},
 'sales_2': {1050: 3226.0,
  992: 11117.0,
  1054: 1613.0,
  1052: 2166.0,
  993: 11117.0,
  980: 3442.0,
  996: 19365.0,
  1017: 3323.0,
  1020: 1411.0,
  1001: 572.0}})
```

I am trying to add a subtotal in multiindex.
I am able to add it with 2 groups like so:

```
dd =  df_from_dict.groupby(['category', 'subcategory'])[['sales_1', 'sales_2']].sum()

s = dd.groupby(level=0).sum()
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s.index, ['Total']])
dd = dd.append(s).sort_index()
dd.loc['Grand Total', :] = dd.sum().values / 2

dd
```

[image]

But when I add 3rd item to the group, `discount`

```
dd =  df_from_dict.groupby(['category', 'subcategory','discount'])[['sales_1', 'sales_2']].sum()

s = dd.groupby(level=0).sum()
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s.index, ['Total']])
dd = dd.append(s).sort_index()
dd.loc['Grand Total', :] = dd.sum().values / 2

dd
```

All of a sudden I get `tuples` instead of normal multiindex. Instead of 3 indexes I get 1 as a `tuple`:

[image]

Whereas I want the same structure as in the first picture but with another level of index. I tried playing with `level=1` parameter in group by but it always ends up in a single index as a tuple, I am not sure where is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem in `Series` called `s` are 2 levels MultiIndex, in `dd` are 3 levels, so in `append` are created `tuple`.

Solution is set 3 levels `MultiIndex` in [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), so same number levels like `dd` and solution working correct:

For avoid sorting all another level in [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) add `sort_remaining=False`:

```
dd =  df_from_dict.groupby(['category', 'subcategory','discount'])[['sales_1', 'sales_2']].sum()

s = dd.groupby(level=0).sum()
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s.index, ['Total'], ['']])
print (s)

dd = dd.append(s).sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False)
dd.loc['Grand Total', :] = dd.sum().values / 2
print (dd)
                                   sales_1  sales_2
category    subcategory discount                   
Bath        Table       30-40     10871.00   1983.0
            Total                 10871.00   1983.0
Dining      Chairs      30-40     53258.04  37031.0
            Total                 53258.04  37031.0
Kitchen     Mirror      30-40      7163.16   2166.0
            Stool       30-40      6736.53   1613.0
            Total                 13899.69   3779.0
Living room chair       30-40      8047.16   3442.0
            mirror      30-40      8601.16  11117.0
            Total                 16648.32  14559.0
Grand Total                       94677.05  57352.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Any idea why in the `living room` category, the `Total` is not in the last position as we sort the index?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - because `.sort_index()`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - answer was edited for avvoid it.